# How can I count overall how many reviews are in an author's all posts?

Tags: django, django-models

I building an e-Commerce website, here also has a system of merchandiser accounts. Every merchandiser can upload their product photo with all information for selling. A merchandiser can sell different types of products. Buyers can give product reviews on the product they bought. ***Now I want to show the overall total of how many buyers have given feedback on seller products.*** For example: `seller-1: 10 reviews, 4.5 star`, `seller-2: 5 reviews, 4.8 star`, `seller-3: 11 reviews, 4.1 star`. How can I do it? Please help me...

***models.py:***

```
class Products(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="merchandise_product_related_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length = 250)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    product_desc = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)


class ProductREVIEWS(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='userREVIEW',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='productREVIEWrelatedNAME',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feedBACK = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.annotate(
    number_of_reviews=Count('merchandise_product_related_name__productREVIEWrelatedNAME')
)
```

The `User` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.number_of_reviews`.

Comment: It shows all users, but I want all reviewers of a seller. I directly copied your code, put it in views, and send it a template.Please see where the problem........counter = User.objects.annotate( number_of_reviews=Count('merchandise_product_related_name__productREVIEWrelatedNAME'))

Comment: @Mossaddak: well the modeling means any user can be a seller...

Comment: yah............